# Editing of Y coordinated of polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, convert

I have recently recieved an extremely complex .dfx polygon file of a mine design in Cape Lo29.The problem appears that the mine engineer has used an old local convention of using negative Y co-ordinate values, essentially plotting the design in the mid Atlantic.

I know the "fix" is fairly simple, the sign of the y-coordinate data needs to be changed to a positive. Is this possible in QGIS (version 3.4.12)?

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my comment, after trying the workflow:

1. Check with epsg.io if there isn't an EPSG-code for the CRS the engineer used. If this fails, continue.
2. Load the `.dxf` into QGIS, using the CRS the data should be in.
3. Mark all elements on the layer (`ctrl+a`), copy and paste them into Excel.
4. In addition to all attributes a leading column will appear, this is the geometry column in WKT (well known text) format.
5. Remove every `-` from this column which is unnecessary via search & replace (`ctrl+h`). Be careful you don't change anything which is actually correct.
6. Save the data to a `.csv`.
7. Use the `add delimited text layer` to load the `.csv` into QGIS, choose the correct CRS and set the geometry definition to WKT.
8. Save the data to your preferred file type.

---

For the future, if possible, ask the guy to do the drawings "correctly" in the first place.

---

Possible issues: This way the geometries get flipped around... so, maybe this wont work as needed after all.

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance. Initially thought it was not working as the .dxf file is very large and complicated. Took over 4 hours to get it into the clipboard in order to paste it into Excel, after that it worked perfectly.

A pity there is not a vector geometry processing tool that can do the same thing.

Comment: You're welcome. Can you give any statement about if the drawings are now correct or if they are mirrored and thus wrong?

Comment: I've sent the converted drawing back to the client and asked for comment. (Its not urgent as they had already gone to the design engineer and asked him to correct his drawing, which he did). I'm still awaiting comment.

When I added the delineated .csv layer and the google maps both where rotated by 180 degrees. I'm not sure why, but it only required that I rotate the work area by 180 degrees. I did a very rough check my taking points at the limits of the original design drawing, converted them through a simple conversion program and plotted them in Google Earth. It was an exact match.

Comment: I have confirmed that the that your methodology has produced the correct result.

Again, many thank.